# Pandas groupby and diff based on two columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda, pandas-groupby

Suppose I have the following `dataframe`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'A': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b'],
        'B': [10, 8, 6, 4],
        'C': [9, 7, 5, 3]
    }
)
```

I want to achieve this:

```
df.groupby('A').B.apply(lambda x: x.diff())
```

But I would like the `diff()` to be between `B` and `C` instead of between `B` and `B` (hope this makes sense). I can do something like this to achieve the `diff()` I'm after:

```
df.C.shift(-1)-df.B
```

But I'm stuck on how I should incorporate it in my `groupby` logic.

The end result would look like:

```
0    NaN
1   -3.0
2    NaN
3   -3.0
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Not sure if this is what you're looking for `df.groupby('A').pipe(lambda g: g.C.last() - g.B.first())`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, Use:

```
s = df.groupby('A').apply(lambda x: x.C - x.B.shift()).reset_index(drop=True)
print(s)
```

This prints:

```
0    NaN
1   -3.0
2    NaN
3   -3.0
```